# refreshing particular div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp

After I got response i want to refresh particular div tag using ajax call

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#add-new-department').submit(function(event) {
            var departmentname = $('#departmentname').val();


            $.ajax({
                url : $("#add-new-department").attr("action"),
                type : "POST",
                data : "departmentname="+departmentname,

                success : function(response) {
                    $('#status').html(response);
                    $('#departmentname').val('');
                    $('#department').load("");   
                }
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        });

    });
</script>
```

I want to update a message in jsp page

```
 <div id="department">Department Updated : <% new Date(); %> </div>
```

My requirement is **just refresh** div tag after ajax call
like

```
 $('#department').refresh();
```

Comment: There is no refresh function in jquery. You have to replace the target element with ajax response.

Comment: You cannot **refresh** a div like this. Instead you can update the content of it.

Comment: By the way in `#department` div, what do you want to display as updated?

Comment: i dont want to send data from ajax function. i just refresh that div please give me suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url : $("#add-new-department").attr("action"),
  type : "POST",
  data : "departmentname="+departmentname,

  success : function(response) {
     $('#status').html(response);
     $('#departmentname').val('');
     $('#department').html('Department Updated: ' + new Date());   
  }
});
```

Comment: i dont want to send data from ajax function. i just refresh that div please give me suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) not `load()` like,

```
$('#department').html("Department Updated : "+new Date());
```

Comment: i dont want to send data from ajax function. i just refresh that div please give me suggestion

Answer (score 0):

use this,write your page name instead content.php

```
$('#department').load('content.php')
```