# Auto refresh only a particular div using javascript.jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page

```
<div id="mainframe">

            <div id="div2"></div>


        <div id="div3"></div>

        <div id="div4">

            <table class="table3">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td width=3%></td>
                        <td class="listtitle">1</td>
                        <td width=5%></td>
                        <td class="listtitle">2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td width=3%></td>
                        <td class="dashboardchart" ><div  style="width:550px ; height:400px"><canvas id="chart_scanner" width="500" height="400">
                        </canvas></div></td>

                        <td class="dashboardchart"><div id="div_chartActivity" style="width:550px ; height:400px"><canvas id="chart_activity" width="500" height="400">
                        </canvas></div></td>
                        <td width=3%></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>  
    </div>
```

I want to implement auto refresh after 15 seconds but only #div3 and #div4 should be reloaded not the entire page.

Can anyone suggest what script should i add to my page

Comment: What does refresh mean in this context? Do we need data from a server or just updating the contents programmatically?

Comment: This question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135332/refreshing-particular-div-using-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval or setTimeout to call a function every X seconds

```
var count = 0;

function refresh() {

//your stuff to refresh your divs here (ajax requests...)

  $("#div3").html(count);
  $("#div4").html(count);
  count++;
  setTimeout(refresh, 1000);
}

refresh();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qbknsu0m/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 15000);

function myTimer() {
    //Here you can update specific part of your page
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

We are initiating a JavaScript timer for 15 seconds. Then when 15 second pass, myTimer function executes. Inside this function you can select the dom element you want to update and set it's innerHTML property to the content you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                    $('#div3').text(
                            'I am getting refreshed every 3 seconds..! Random Number ==> '
                                    + randomnumber);
                    $('#div4').text(
                            'I am getting refreshed every 3 seconds..! Random Number ==> '
                                    + randomnumber);
                }, 3000);
            });
```

Comment: Guys. I have chart in those two div, and want to reload the entire div as it is. As in, chart is getting updated from database, on refresh i want to update those charts in those div

Comment: Well, where do you get the data from? Is it an xml, or database or just some files? And is this html page generated through java or any other language or is it static?

Comment: This data is coming from server and rendered in html, now i want to have auto refresh in which the header and other static data should remain as it is. only the div with those charts should be reloaded after a particular interval

Comment: You need to aquire the modified chart data by an ajax request, just refreshing the part of the page would not work, because the data keeps changing. So you must make an ajax request every few seconds and fetch to new data generated by the server from a request.