# Refreshing a particular div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written a code in which i want to reload a particular div. I am using jquery for refreshing that div but the problem is overlapping occurs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var refresh = setInterval(function () {
        refreshapppane();
    }, 10000);
    function refreshapppane() {
        $('#frmRadio1').load("Business_Impacts.jsp");
        //alert();
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div id="main_container">
        some code
        <div id="frmRadio"> refresh this pane
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135332/refreshing-particular-div-using-jquery]

Comment: Seeing the answers, your question is obviously not clear enough. What overlapping? A picture would help. Also fix your code, so it actually works (The IDs must match) and we can actually reproduce that overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function refreshapppane() {
  $('#frmRadio').append("Business_Impacts.jsp");
  //alert();
}
setInterval(refreshapppane, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main_container">
  some code
  <div id="frmRadio">refresh this pane
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Your **ID** not matching.

Comment: Nice catch, even though OP gave a totally different description of the problem!

Comment: Business_Impacts.jsp is the file name

Comment: @Jack i am just showing the append so you can see that it is running you can change it to load or what ever you need

Comment: @Jack Close the OP :) happy coding mate

Comment: `append` method only append data, not clear the old data,

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You should have mentioned that in the comments.